# Assuming that $I,J\subset S$ are monomial ideals, is it true that $I+J$ is monomial? What about $IJ$ and $I\cap J$?

Tags: ideals, monomial-ideals

Let $\mathbb{k}$ be a field and $S=\mathbb{k}[x_1,\dots,x_k]$ be a ring of polynomials over $\mathbb{k}$.

Assuming that ideals $I,J\subset S$ are monomial, is it true that $I+J$ is monomial? What about $IJ$ and $I\cap J$?

I do not know how to approach this problem. If we take for example $I=(x_1,x_2)$ and $I=(x_2,x_3)$ then how to find $I+J$ and so on?

Comment: What is a monomial ideal?  An ideal generated by monomials?

Comment: @Batominovski, yes

Comment: Then, suppose $I$ is generated by monomials $m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_p$ and $J$ is generated by monomials $n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_q$ (there are finitely many of them by Hilbert's Basis Theorem).  Shouldn't $I+J$ be generated by monomials $m_1,m_2,\ldots,m_p,n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_q$?  Shouldn't $I\cdot J$ be generated by monomials of the form $m_in_j$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,p$ and $j=1,2,\ldots,q$?  Shouldn't $I\cap J$ be generated by monomials of the form $\text{lcm}(m_i,n_j)$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,p$ and $j=1,2,\ldots,q$?

Comment: Assuming that you're right, then what's left to show?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  But well, I guess you can try to prove my three claims.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this it is useful to think of ideals in terms of generating sets.  You know what this is already because monomial ideal is defined in terms of generators.

Now $I+J$ is another way of saying "the ideal generated by $I$ and $J$".  Perhaps prove this first.  Then if $I$ and $J$ are generated by some subsets $I_0$ and $J_0$, what could you use as generators for $I+J$?  For $I\cdot J$?

Answer (score 1):

$I\cap J$ is a monomial ideal

We use a result which is stated that
$I$ is a monomial ideal then for any $f\in I$, one has $supp(f)\subseteq I$.

Let $f\in I\cap J$ as both $I$ and $J$ are monomial ideals
implies $supp(f)\subseteq I$ and $supp(f)\subseteq J $.
which implies $supp(f)\subseteq I\cap J$.

Hence $I\cap J$  is monomial ideal